# How to make bulk updates/inserts on time series data

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to create this question to specifically address a relatively niche, but important problem to solve - optimizing the process of making massive bulk updates/inserts to time series data on a daily basis. I'll illustrate what I've been able to come up with on my own (as I've been working on this problem for quite some time now) to help anyone else who runs into this problem (I've had a few friends ask me for advice on this exact problem and we haven't found a lot of resources online).

---

Let's say I have a table structure like this, where I have a meta table which has 1 row per person. And another table that tracks the time series data for each person.

```
create table meta (
  item_id bigserial primary key,
  name text
);

create table time_series_table (
  item_id bigserial references meta(item_id),
  date date,
  value int
);

create index time_series_table_idx
on mytable(item_id, date);
```

Every day, I have to perform very large, upsert-esque, updates on this table using a data-dump I get. Meaning, I get new data for today (which I need to insert) but I also might get updated data for the past couple days (which means I need to update those existing records). Every day I get ~10million rows which I need to check against my existing table, `time_series_table`, which contains ~800million rows already. Needless to say... this operation requires thoughtful optimization. So far I've done a decent job optimizing this, but I'm curious to get an expert opinion. Maybe I'm not considering a more efficient index type or something?

Anyway, here's my current strategy. (the first step is to load the incoming csv into a temporary table which, for this example, we'll assume has already been done, and we'll call that incoming dataset of ~10million rows `incoming`). Remember, the most expensive operation will be the merging of both the `item_id` and `date` fields between the `incoming` and existing datasets so that we can determine which rows to insert, and which ones to update.

At a high level, here's what the strategy looks like...

1. Select a pseudo-partition of the existing ~800 million rows so we don't have to merge on rows we don't need to. For example, incoming data will never go back further than 20 days ago, so we remove anything < 20 days ago.
2. Create a temporary table, `upserts`, by merging incoming data with our pseudo-partition on both the `item_id` and `date` columns. This will be a `incoming -> left merge -> existing`. If the `existing.item_id` field is null here, that will tell us that the record does not exist in our database (i.e. it needs to be inserted).
3. Select rows from our `upserts` where the `existing.item_id is null` to get rows we need to insert.
4. Select rows from our `upserts` where the `existing.item_id is not null` (record already exists) and the existing value is different than the incoming value (record should be updated to reflect the incoming value)

```
-- Just assume this is our incoming data of ~10 million rows
create temp table incoming;

/*
    Start by matching the incoming data with the existing data
    so that we can figure out which rows we should insert and which
    ones we should update.
 */
create temp table upserts as (
    select
        incoming.item_id,
        incoming.date,
        incoming.value,
        existing.value as existing_value,
        case
            when existing.item_id is null then false -- because this is a left join, this id being null would mean it doesn't exist
            else true
        end as record_exists -- boolean telling us whether or not the record exists in the database
    from incoming
    left join (

        -- Get a pseudo-partition of the existing dataset so we don't have to scan all 800 million rows during merge operation
        select *
        from time_series_table -- This is our existing table of ~800 million rows
        where date > now() - interval '20 days' -- incoming data would only refer to the past 20 days
            and item_id in (select distinct item_id from incoming) -- we only care about the item ids that come from the incoming dataset

    ) existing on incoming.item_id = existing.item_id and incoming.date = existing.date -- match on both the item_id and date
);

create temp table insertables as (
    select item_id, date, value
    from upserts
    where record_exists is false -- if the record wasn't matched then it's an insert
);

create temp table updateables as (
    select item_id, date, value
    from upserts
    where record_exists is true -- in order to be an update, it must be something that is already in our db
        and value is distinct from existing_value -- the existing value must be different from the incoming value
);

-- Finally...
-- Insert the insertables
-- Update the updateables
```

Like I said, the biggest bottleneck is where I have to merge the incoming to our existing dataset on both the `item_id` and `date` columns... which makes sense... but I'm not sure how I can further optimize this? Here are a couple of my ideas...

1. Use a different index that is optimized for this type of operation.
2. Create a 4th column that is a combination of both the `item_id` and `date` columns and put an index on that so that we only have to merge on a single column.
3. Use partitions? (Never used these before, so I'm not sure if/how this would help)

Does anybody have any expert knowledge on something like this?

Comment: I find it strange that you get so many values per `date` that you can't distinguish. Typically the most efficient way of doing an UPSERT is to use `insert ... on conflict()` but this won't work as you don't have a proper unique constraint that could be used to match incoming values to existing values (as the primary key is generated and has no relation to the "content" of your data)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so in reality, the `item_id` is actually a foreign key, and the primary key of this table is a composite of `item_id` and `date`. So, I _could_ use your strategy, but in my experience, postgres's `upsert` technique does not scale to this size very well. I'm setting up a test environment right now to give precise numbers as evidence to that.

Comment: If `item_id` is a foreign key, defining it as `bigserial` makes zero sense.

Comment: "so in reality, the item_id is actually a foreign key"  If you want things highly optimized, you need to hew closely to reality.  If the schema you show us only rhymes with your real schema, advice you get will likely be of dubious usefulness.

Comment: It is odd that you show the commands for creating the temp tables, which apparently is not the bottleneck, but don't show the merging command, which you say is the bottleneck.  Please show the command which is the bottleneck, as well as the EXPLAIN or better yet the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for it.

Comment: @jjanes i do show the place where the bottleneck happens, it's where the merge happens on both the `item_id` and the `date` at the bottom of the creation of the `upserts` temp table. I select from the incoming data, and merge it to the existing dataset.

Comment: I'll also just add that the `insert ... on conflict()` strategy suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name has an issue, where it will write updates that might not need to happen. For example, say the conflict happens, and it defaults to performing the write operation, but the new value is not different to the incoming value. Because there are so many rows to check per day, this stacks up quickly. And performing a check for different values for each `on conflict` stacks as well. I'm working on pulling together some tests for these and will report back soon.